# Main reason for the choice of .NET to build StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm new to SO and I find this site very well done. So I was wondering [What Was Stack Overflow Built With?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/) and I easily find the answer.

Now I'm curious to know  **what is the main reason of this choice**?

Comment: I guess familiarity with what he already knew, and he probably chose to learn that because it fits the computer environment he lives in best. I love how this site shows of the capabilities of ASP.NET. :)

Comment: Yes it's impressive!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main reason, it was the development stack Jeff, Jarrod and Geoff knew best when they embarked on the mission.

The other big reason would probably be [bizspark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/default.aspx) which allowed us to delay buying very expensive licenses.

Comment: Those "expensive" licenses have nothing to do with .net though. It is all SQL Server. Nothing says you have to use SQL Server because you use .net

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer! I have never heard about bizspark programm before, that's quite interesting! I made some further research and I found this article http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/stack-overflow-and-bizspark/ , written by Jeff Atwood, that also give some answers about the question.

Answer (score 4):

Also somewhat relevant, I think, is [this Joel piece from September 2006](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/09/01.html) (my emphases):

> What I do know for sure, though, is two things:
>
> 1. People all over the world are constantly building web applications using .NET, using Java, and using PHP all the time. **None of them are failing *because of the choice of technology*.**
> 2. All of these environments are large and complex and you really need at least one architect with serious experience developing for the
>      one you choose, because otherwise you'll do things wrong and wind up
>      with messy code that needs to be restructured.
>
> ...
>
> How do you decide between C#, Java, PHP, and Python? **The only real
>   difference is which one *you* know better**. If you have a serious Java
>   guru on your team who has build several large systems successfully
>   with Java, you're going to be a hell of a lot more successful with
>   Java than with C#, not because Java is a better language (it's not,
>   but the differences are too minor to matter) but because he knows it
>   better. Etc.